# What will the below mentioned syntax do while running a Jenkins pipeline?agent [ label 'slave' ]

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

What will the below mentioned syntax do while running a Jenkins pipeline?
agent [ label 'slave' ]

Choose the best option

1. It will execute the pipeline on Jenkins master node.

2.It will create a node with label slave

3.It will execute the pipeline on Jenkins slave.

4.It will create a workspace named slave​

Comment: It will error out. The right syntax for an agent with the label would be agent { label 'agent_label_name'}. [Jenkins Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

Comment: agent { label 'agent_label_name'} - with this, If you give a nonexisting label agent name, the job will wait with a message - Still waiting to schedule task There are no nodes with the label ‘xyz’ and Timedout some point of time